# React.JS react-router-dom v6.8 block navigation w/ custom modal

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently working on implementing a custom modal to replace the use of `window.confirm()` in order to notify the user about any changes that might be lost if they navigate away from the current page. However, I've run into an issue where I'm receiving an error message stating that `A router only supports one blocker at a time`, and as a result, the modal isn't opening and the route isn't being changed back. I have seen many examples, but for v6.8 nothing is working so I was trying to implement it by myself but got stuck.
I made an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-galileo-9vlr39) as well. Thank you.

Here is the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  useBeforeUnload,
  unstable_useBlocker as useBlocker
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

function usePrompt(message, { beforeUnload } = {}) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

  const handleConfirm = () => {
    blocker.allow();
    setShow(false);
  };

  let blocker = useBlocker(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      setShow(true);
      return true;
    }, [])
  );

  let prevState = React.useRef(blocker.state);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (blocker.state === "blocked") {
      blocker.reset();
    }
    prevState.current = blocker.state;
  }, [blocker]);

  useBeforeUnload(
    React.useCallback(
      (event) => {
        if (beforeUnload && blocker.state === "blocked") {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.returnValue = message;
        }
      },
      [message, beforeUnload, blocker.state]
    ),
    { capture: true }
  );

  return (
    <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Are you sure?</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{message}</Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleConfirm}>
          Confirm
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default function Prompt({ when, message, ...props }) {
  usePrompt(when ? message : false, props);
  return null;
}
```

And usage

```
<Prompt
  when={true}
  message="If you leave changes will be lost. Continue?"
  beforeUnload={true}
/>
```

Comment: Isn't the current recommendation from the `react-router-dom` maintainers to ***not*** block the UI and instead just save any changes prior to a user leaving the page? In any case I was able to get the blocker to work by using one accessed via the `router` reference, but then the UI runs into the issue that React renders are ***synchronous*** and the modal confirmation handler is inherently ***asynchronous*** and the blocker can't unblock correctly to allow the navigation transition. My suggestion is to take a step back and rethink your UI/UX.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, but since the project is for educational purposes, I don't care about recommendations, I just want to see if it's possible this way. Thank you for the comment ^~^

Comment: Roger that. It's possibly doable, but likely not worth the effort forcing RRDv6 to do something it's not designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to achieve a similar result for a while now and I think I finally figured it out. I found this example after I figured it out, which will definitely be of help:

https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/navigation-blocking?file=src%2Fapp.tsx

> I've run into an issue where I'm receiving an error message stating that A router only supports one blocker at a time

This is a known bug from 6.8.1, so I am still using 6.8.0 and it works fine.
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/10073

Also be aware that unstable_useBlocker is seems to be only for Single Page Applications as well indicated by the xmldoc

> Allow the application to block navigations within the SPA and present the user a confirmation dialog to confirm the navigation.  Mostly used to avoid
> using half-filled form data.  This does not handle hard-reloads or
> cross-origin navigations.

I've gone and modified your sandbox a little bit to make it work, including downgrading to 6.8.0 to remove that pesky warning. When you try to navigate and a blocker is present and enabled, the blocker sets the state to "Blocked". The state is not set when you set it to true on initialisation. I believe you have to use useNavigation as well for the unstable_useBlocker to work. It was very confusing for me at first. See here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-6-8-blocker-qmvie0

The example has a bug when you cancel the modal, you cannot click the same link, but I do not think it has to do with the router or blocker (It seems that the nav link becomes "active" or something when clicked, so they cannot be clicked again)

```
export default function Prompt({ message }) {
let blocker = useBlocker(true); //useBlocker(isFormDirty)

//in ts, if blocker.state() === "blocked", else blocker.reset() and proceed() can be undefined
  const handleClose = () => blocker.reset(); 
  const handleConfirm = () => blocker.proceed();

  return (
    <Modal show={blocker.state === "blocked"} onHide={handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Are you sure?</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{message}</Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleConfirm}>
          Confirm
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your response. This is exactly what I needed. Drew Reese advised me to find another way, which I did. I ended up saving the state and reviving it later. But you made it work, which is amazing. Later I will implement this method too. I was so anxious to do it this way. Thank you again.

Comment: Please edit you answer and post fixed code as well, because if the sandbox will be deleted, someone will able to see it anyway ^~^